# Rancher helm chart, cannot find secret bootstrap-secret

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl, rancher, k3s, helm3

So I am trying to deploy rancher on my K3S cluster.
I installed it using the documentation and helm: [Rancher documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/installation/install-rancher-on-k8s/)
While I am getting access using my loadbalancer. I cannot find the secret to insert into the setup.

They discribe the following command for getting the token:

```
kubectl get secret --namespace cattle-system bootstrap-secret -o go-template='{{.data.bootstrapPassword|base64decode}}{{ "\n" }}'
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "bootstrap-secret" not found
```

And also I cannot find the bootstrap-secret inside the namespace cattle-system.
So can somebody help me out where I need to look?

Comment: It seems, you need to specify the password while installing it with HELM https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/installation/resources/bootstrap-password/#specifying-the-bootstrap-password-in-helm-installs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was with the same problem. So I figured it out with the following commands:

1. I installed the helm chart with "--set bootstrapPassword=Changeme123!", for example:

   **helm upgrade --install  

   --namespace cattle-system 

   --set hostname=rancher.example.com 

   --set replicas=3 

   --set bootstrapPassword=Changeme123! 

   rancher rancher-stable/rancher**
2. I forced a hard reset, because even if I had setted the bootstrap password in the installation helm chart command, I was not able to login. So, I used the following command to hard reset:

   **kubectl -n cattle-system exec $(kubectl -n cattle-system get pods -l app=rancher | grep '1/1' | head -1 | awk '{ print $1 }') -- reset-password**

So, I hope that can help you.